# How to lock the rotation of an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

Tags: camera, containers

In my endless quest to lock the rotation of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (like in the camera.app), I've decided to try VC containment.

My thought is that if I place AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer code into a separate VC and disable its rotations, I should be able to have a locked '*view*' as my background layer (augmented reality app).

But when I attempt to do this, AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer simply fails to work at all and I get no camera video.

Below is my setup.

in **ViewController.m** :

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) cameraViewController *cameraVC;

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        self.cameraVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cameraVC"];

        [self addChildViewController:self.cameraVC];

        [self.view addSubview:self.cameraVC.view];
```

in **cameraViewController.m** :

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"cameraViewController : viewDidAppear");

     self.captureManager = [[CaptureSessionManager alloc] init];
     [self.captureManager addVideoInput];
     [self.captureManager addVideoPreviewLayer];

     CGRect layerRect = self.cameraView.bounds;
     [[self.captureManager previewLayer] setBounds:layerRect];
     [[self.captureManager previewLayer] setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(layerRect), CGRectGetMidY(layerRect))];

     [self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:self.captureManager.previewLayer];

     [[self.captureManager captureSession] startRunning];

}
```

But when I set **cameraViewController.m** to be the root controller loaded automatically first in my storyboard, the camera video (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) works fine.  (minus the rotation annoyance)

Why does it work as the root VC but not as a child VC?

[I'm using XCode 4.5, iOS 6.0, and storyboards.]